# Is there a way to assign multiple static IPs to an Amazon Lightsail instance?

Tags: wordpress, multisite, webmin, amazon-lightsail, virtualmin

I am currently using Amazon Lightsail to provide Wordpress Multisite Hosting for a couple of my clients, but I'm running into an issue.

I am working with the following technologies:

1) Wordpress Multisite (2 installations on the same server)
2) Webmin / Virtualmin for server management
3) Amazon Lightsail for Server provisioning
4) Amazon Lightsail Static IP (Pointed to the lightsail server)

Currently Amazon Lightsail only allows 1 static IP address to be assigned to an instance, however, to avoid DNS conflicts, I want to give a dedicated IP address to each wordpress multisite installation.

Webmin / Virtualmin has the ability to manage multiple IP addresses and allows me to assign a specific IP address to a new virtual server once it's provisioned. (detailed here: https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/add-new-ip-address-virtualmin/)

The issue I'm facing is that if a new website (a wordpress multisite's child-site) is set up, the two installations will get "confused" on where to route the domain if they are both running on the same IP address. The current **workaround** i've used is to set up the domain as an alias to the multisite installation I want to be used. This is effective, but inefficient.

I'm a newbie when it comes to the in-depth setup of server networking so I am hoping to have some assistance here. answering one of these questions may allow me to achieve this goal:
 Is there any way to use an ADDITIONAL static IP address with Amazon lightsail? 
Is there a way to register / lease / purchase an IP Address from an EXTERNAL source and make it work with my installation?
Is there a way to use [this multiple IPv4 addresses for EC2 Solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html) on Lightsail?
If nothing else, I would just provision a new server and separate the two multisite installations, but then I need to double-up my server management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present time, there is no way to assign two static IP's to a single lightsail instance.

FWIW: I run multiple wordpress instances on a single lightsail instance with no issues.  I'm not using multi-site though.

If you're running multiple wordpress multi-site instances on a single server, you probably want to think about using two lightsail instances.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to just launch another lightsail instance and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to assign multiple static IPs to a single Lightsail instance at this time. However, there are a few workarounds that you can use:

Provision two Lightsail instances and assign a static IP to each instance. This is the most straightforward solution, but it will require you to manage two separate servers.

Use a third-party DNS service to manage your DNS records. This will allow you to create separate DNS records for each WordPress multisite installation, even if they are both hosted on the same Lightsail instance.

Use a load balancer to distribute traffic between the two WordPress multisite installations. This will ensure that both installations are always accessible, even if one of them goes down.

If you are not comfortable managing multiple servers or configuring DNS records, then the best option for you may be to use a third-party hosting provider that offers multiple IP addresses.

Here are some of the third-party hosting providers that offer multiple IP addresses:

- Bluehost
- HostGator
- GoDaddy
- SiteGround
- A2 Hosting

These providers all offer a variety of plans that include multiple IP addresses, so you can choose the plan that best meets your needs.

I hope this helps!